# java.io.IOException: Permission denied while creating new file from Tomcat in Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a Grails application deployed on Tomcat 7. Here is my code fragment which tries to create a new file:

```
def path = "/var/csvs" + file.fileItem.fileName
def fileInputStream = file.inputStream
File f = new File(path)
if (!f.exists()) {
   f.createNewFile()
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Permission denied. Stacktrace follows:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
```

I have already given rwx permission to tomcat7(the user under which tomcat is running). So why am I not able to create a new file?
Is it that "/var/csvs" is trying to create a file relative to the tomcat webapps directory? If yes then how should I create a file at /var/csvs (where csvs is a folder I have created under the /var)?

**EDIT:**

Here is my permissions on /var/csvs folder:

```
root@MyIp:/# ls -ld /var/csvs
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Jun  3 15:44 /var/csvs
```

So clearly tomcat7 is the owner of that directory and mode is 777

Comment: What is the value of `path`?

Comment: @immibis its like "/var/csvs/somefile.csv". I am trying to write in some new csv files in the /var/csvs directory

Comment: What are the permissions and owner of /var/csvs?

Comment: Please type the exact linux commands for giving permission.

Comment: @YairZaslavsky is it not enough that the user **HAS** required permissions?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the problem. 
Any relevant info can help.
In addition, are you sure you're running tomcat on behalf of user tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the code be like

```
def path = "/var/csvs/" + file.fileItem.fileName // notice the trailing fwd slash
```

otherwise it is very likely you're trying to write into the `/var` directory.